# Confusion about the definition of ideal (of ring of algebraic integers)

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, discriminant

I am studying algebraic number theory and am confused about the following lemma. We prove that if $I \subset O_K$ a non-zero ideal then $$\textrm{disc}(I) = \textrm{disc}(O_K)\cdot N(I)$$
Then somewhere later on the author considers the case where $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and wants to find the index of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ in $O_K$. So he substitutes $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ for $I$ in the above formula and calculates it straightforwardly. However I am confused as $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ does not seem to be an ideal of $O_K$. I.e. it does not absorb products. I am missing something here?

Comment: It'd be interesting to know the story around: where is this taken from? Some site, some book...?

Comment: An examples class. I can't give a reference I'm afraid. It seems strange because, if $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is not an ideal, what does it even mean to define its index?

Comment: Probably the index of $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ as an additive subgroup, it is still finite.

Comment: Look at the Gaussian integers $\Bbb Z[i]$, and their subring $\Bbb Z[3i]$. As abelian groups the index is $3$; when you calculate their discriminants, the big ring has discriminant $-4$, while the subring has discriminant $-36$. In general, the discriminants are related by a factor equal to the square of the index, as here.

Comment: So you are saying the the formula is true even when we substitute non-ideals in?